# Celery - Task Id max length?

Tags: celery

I would like to store celery task id in a model in a CharField my Django database. I am required to specify a max length. What is the max length for celery task id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Celery uses Python's standard library `uuid` module ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html ) to generate task IDs. This module generates standard [RFC-4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html) UUIDs, which means 32 hexadecimal numbers with 4 dashes in between so the Python generated UUID strings are always 36 chars long (example: `6f726825-ccef-4be1-b64c-ae13605d48db`).

Comment: Do you know why this package https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/blob/master/django_celery_results/models.py specifies a max_length of 255 for the task id?

Comment: Apparently Celery allows specifying the task ID, so probably for that reason django-celery specifiex max lenght to 255... If you, like me, never do this, you are good with length 36 as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Maybe because the memcache maximum key length is 250 characters? https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/memcached.h#L60